# Authenticate API using Owin Token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I have existing MVC website where form authentication was used and identity was stored in session. We modified Account controller (LogOn method) code and and removed the session and authenticate using Owin.

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(properties, claimsIdentity)
```

On startup, it is using CookieAuthentication.

This works fine for subsequent request, as the token is stored in cookie.

We also need to send this token as bearer (or in custom header) so that api can authenticate the request. Since the API is hosted at different server, we set same machine key for both MVC & WebAPI.

Howver, this does not work. Is there any better way to decrypt the token and get the claims details? Or validate the token seamlessly and allow request if authenticated.

Web Startup

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = Auth_type,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/home/about"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/home/index"),
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Never,
            CookieHttpOnly = false
        });
```

home/About

```
if (!Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var id = GetId() as MyIdentity;
            var prop = Getprop();
            Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(prop, id);
        }
```

Api Startup

```
var OAuthOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                AuthenticationType = OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            };
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthOptions);
```

API Authorize Attribute

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            // check identity here
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        }
    }
```

JS call to API

```
var token = getCookie(".AspNet.ApplicationCookie");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    beforeSend: function (request) {
                        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                    },
                    url: "http://localhost:1231/authapi/api/values/get?id=1",

                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert("Success" + msg)
                    },
                    error: function (d) {
                        debugger;
                        alert("Error" + d.responseText)
                    }

                });
```

Comment: Did you try with UseJwtBearerAuthentication instead of OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions?

Comment: I am able to make this work using creating new class inherited from IDataProtector  and use it for keys encryption

Comment: Ok i have an exact setup for our website but we use the UseJwtBearerAuthentication. But good you got it working :)